# Recursion in functional programming will not give high concurrency. Is it correct?

Tags: functional-programming

I am new to functional programming. Loops in imperative programming replaces recursion in FP. Another statement is FP gives high concurrency. The instructions being executed parallelly on multi-core/cpu systems as the data is immutable.

Whereas in recursion, steps cannot be executed parallelly due to a step execution is dependent on the previous steps result.

So, I am assuming that recursion in FP will not give high concurrency. Am I correct?

Comment: It really depends on the specific implementation. There's no general rule that an optimizing compiler can't turn something expressed recursively into an iterative or parallel process.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.  You cannot get more execution parallelism than the data parallelism; this is [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law).  However, you frequently have more data parallelism than is expressed in typical sequential algorithms, whether functional or imperative.  Consider for example taking the scalar multiple of a vector: (note: this is some made-up algol-style language):[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law)

```
function scalar_multiple(scalar c, vector v) {
    vector v1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length(v); i++) {
        v1[i] = c * v[i];
    }
    return v1;
}
```

Obviously, this isn't going to run in parallel.  The situation isn't improved if we re-write in a functional language, using recursion (you can think of this as Haskell):

```
scalar_multiple c [] = []
scalar_multiple c (x:xn) = c * x : scalar_multiple c xn
```

This is still a sequential algorithm!

However, you can notice that there is no data dependency --- you don't actually need the result of earlier / later multiplications to calculate later ones.  So we have the potential for parallelization here.  This can be accomplished in an imperative language:

```
function scalar_multiple(scalar c, vector v) {
    vector v1;
    parallel_for (int i in 0..length(v)-1) {
        v1[i] = c * v[i];
    }
    return v1;
}
```

But this `parallel_for` is a dangerous construct.  Consider a search function:

```
function first(predicate p, vector v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length(v); i++) {
        if (p(v[i])) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If we try speeding this up by replacing `for` with `parallel_for`:

```
function first(predicate p, vector v) {
    parallel_for (int i in 0..length(v)-1) {
        if (p(v[i])) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now we won't necessarily return the index of the *first* element to satisfy the condition, just *an* element that satisfies it.  We broke the contract of the function by parallelizing it.

The obvious solution is 'don't allow `return` inside `parallel_for`.  But there are lots of other dangerous constructs; in fact, you'll notice I had to abandon the C-style `for` loop because the increment-and-test pattern itself is dangerous in parallel languages.  Consider:

```
function sequence(int n) {
    vector v;
    int c = 0;
    parallel_for (int i = 0..n-1) {
        v[i] = c++;
    }
    return v;
}
```

This is again a 'toy' example ("just use `v[i] = i;`!"), but it illustrates the point: this function initializes `v` in a random order, due to parallelism.  So it turns out that the constructs that are 'safe' to use inside a construct like `parallel_for` are precisely the constructs that are allowed in purely-functional languages, which makes adding parallel constructs to those languages 'safer' than adding them to imperative languages.

[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) This is just a very simple example; of course, real parallelism involves finding bigger chunks of work to parallize than this!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understand you right, but it generally depends on what you want to accomplish.

One recursion alone cannot execute its subcalls parallel. But you CAN have 2 recursions working on the same dataset. i.e. processing an array from left AND from right simultaneosly trough two concurrent running recursive functions. Those (two) functions can then (theretically) run parallel.

In detail it does not matter if you have a recursive function or a function with a loop inside as long as there is a function who can run on its own. So in respect to your question:

No, a recursive function per definition does not give you any concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Loops are replaced by higher-order functions more frequently than by direct recursion.  Recursion is sort of a catch-all measure in functional programming for when higher-order functions don't already exist for what you need to do.

For example, if you want to run the same calculation on all elements of a list, you use a `map`, which is highly parallelizable. Finding which elements meet certain criteria is a `filter`, also highly parallelizable.

Some algorithms just plain require the result of the previous iteration in order to proceed.  Those are the ones that tend to require a recursive function, and you're right, they are not generally easy to make highly concurrent.